# LinearLayout Center

Tags: android, center, android-linearlayout

I've a little problem with alignement in LinearLayout.

I'm trying to have the frist two elements with left alignement, and the third at the center of the screen.

Here is my code (cleaned from id, text, src) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_background"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[alt text http://img807.imageshack.us/img807/5953/imageg.png](http://img807.imageshack.us/img807/5953/imageg.png)

Here is what I'm trying to do, pink and yellow on left, red in the center

```
pink = imageview
yellow = 1st texview
red = 2nd textview
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

So the code you need to use is the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`. Have pink just be a normal child. Have yellow use `android:layout_toRightOf` to put it to the right of pink. Have red use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`.